# jquery change style of a div on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div, with a specific style(let's say a certain background).

What I want is, when one clicks on a list element having that div applied another specific style (another background type) to be applied to that div,

If another area in a different element belonging to that div is clicked, the style should not change.

Is it possible using jquery? thank you!

**Edit:** (my function does some other things also. but the changing color doesn;t work as i want. it changes the background of all items i click, not only the last clicked.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product_types > li').click(function() {
        $(this)
        .css('backgroundColor','#EE178C')
        .siblings()
        .css('backgroundColor','#ffffff');

        $('#submit_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#number').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: What if I want to change the style/css reference for the perticular division runtime with JQuery ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As what I have understand on your question, this is what you want.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSAjV/2/) of the below:

```js
$('.childDiv').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
  $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
});
```

```css
.parentDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: relative;
}
.childDiv {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
  Group 1
  <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
    Child 2
  </div>
</div>
<div id="divParent2" class="parentDiv">
  Group 2
  <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
    Child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: an improvement suggestion:
use the jquery siblings()
http://jsfiddle.net/P5DCg/1/

Comment: @dana: your welcome :) also have a look on the suggestion of @Guy it should be much better

Comment: @Guy - i have tried your code, but it aplies this style to every html element i click on, and i want it to apply only on the last one. any ideas why? thanks very much

Comment: @Dana - please try to post some of your code so we could have a look on it and see what we can do about it :)

Comment: If you want to be defensive, use .closest() instead of .parent(). Parent could not be as future proof as closest if some zidiot messes with your html.

Comment: What if I want to change the style/css reference for the perticular division runtime with JQuery ?

Comment: Based on the other samples shown here, I've built this sample which uses several of these css/jquery techniques to toggle colors on divs. Just click on the number segments to toggle them on/off. Click on a colored square to changes all lit segments to the selected color.  http://jsfiddle.net/mattslay/FtmMk/

Answer (score 4):

you can use `.css` method of jquery..

reference [css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div_one').bind('click', function() {
    $('#div_two').addClass('large');
  });
});
```

If I understood your question.

Or you can modify css directly:

```
var $speech = $('div.speech');
var currentSize = $speech.css('fontSize');
$speech.css('fontSize', '10px');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to change the CSS style of an element by clicking an item in a `ul` list. Am I right?

HTML:

```
<div class="results" style="background-color:Red;">
</div>

 <ul class="colors-list">
     <li>Red</li>
     <li>Blue</li>
     <li>#ffee99</li>
 </ul>
```

jquery

```
$('.colors-list li').click(function(e){
    var color = $(this).text();
    $('.results').css('background-color',color);
});
```

Note that jquery can use `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass` if you want to use classes rather than inline styling. This means that you can do something like that:

```
$('.results').addClass('selected');
```

And define the 'selected' styling in the CSS.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uuJmP/